# selector jquery div checkbox

Tags: jquery, coffeescript, jquery-selectors

HI i want to click in div call the function but am lost

this is my html

```
    <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label id="ya" class="">
                <input name="operario[autorizador]" type="hidden" value="0">
**<div class="icheckbox_minimal"** aria-checked="false" aria-disabled="false" style="position: relative;">
<input id="operario_autorizador" name="operario[autorizador]" type="checkbox" value="1" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;">
<ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; opacity: 0; background: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></ins></div> 
                Es autorizador?
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
       </div>
```

this is my javascript coffee

```
$ ->
$(document).on 'click', '.icheckbox_minimal', (evt) ->
        console.log("HOLLLLA")
```

Comment: Is jQuery.js included in page? What errors are thrown in browser console?

Comment: yes Jquery.js included, nothing error dont found

Comment: Hi friend this is the code for jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/HalleyRV/q5duw8xa/#base

Answer (score 0):

You need to indent the `$(document).on` line so that is actually inside the `$ ->`.

Coffeescript uses whitespace to define the scope of a function, so the `$(document).on` code is being run before the page has loaded.

Not sure if this will fix the whole problem, but it's a start.

Comment: Hi Scott hi scott really if I put a div id a father if he reads the event but more I try with nested div does not work me

Comment: There is a disconnect between your html and the jQuery selector you are using.  Part of the problem is that your text is outside of the div/ins tag that you are assigning the click event too.  Your html is a little busted.  I'd recommend trimming it down to the absolute minimum you need.  Your coffeescript/javascript is fine, assuming you adjust the selector to match whatever html you wind up with.